# react-native pass state globally using redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

In my app, the LoginScreen(fristScreen) could login with facebook and when the user successfully login, the app receives a facebook `access token` and navigates to the next screen(VerifyScreen). In the VerifyScreen(secondScreen), when I click a button I want to bring the global state `facebookToken` and display on screen. Below is my code:

App.js

```
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { createDrawerNavigator, createStackNavigator, } from 'react-navigation'

const reducer = (state = '', action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'UPDATE':
            return { facebookToken: action.payload}
  }
    return state
}

const store = createStore(reducer)

class App extends Component {
  render(){
    return(

      <Provider store={store}>
        <View style={{flex:1,backgroundColor:'transparent'}}>
          <AppDrawerNavigator/>
        </View>
      </Provider> 
    )
  }
}
```

LoginScreen.js

```
import { LoginButton, AccessToken } from 'react-native-fbsdk';
import {connect} from 'react-redux'

class LoginScreen extends Component{

  <View>
            <LoginButton
              onLoginFinished={
                (error, result) => {
                  if (error) {
                    console.log("login has error: " + result.error);
                  } else if (result.isCancelled) {
                    console.log("login is cancelled.");
                  } else {
                    this.props.navigation.navigate('VerifyScreen')
                    AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken().then(
                      (data) => {
                        this.setState({facebookToken:data.accessToken},
                    () =>  console.log('facebookToken.state',this.state.facebookToken),
//Here I am getting undefined for 'this.props.facebookToken'                        
() =>  console.log('facebookToken.props',this.props.facebookToken),
                        console.log('facebook login success!'),
                        console.log('facebook token is:',data.accessToken.toString()))
                      }
                    )
                  }
                }
              }
              onLogoutFinished={() => console.log("logout.")}/>

//I created a button to see if I could call global state. but this would give me an error "state is not defined"
<Button
            title="call global state"
            onPress={() => this.props.increaseCounter()}/>


</View>

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        facebookToken: state.facebookToken
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        increaseCounter: () => dispatch({ type: 'UPDATE',payload: state.facebookToken }),
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(LoginScreen)
```

VerifyScreen.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
    View,
    Text,
    StyleSheet,
    Button
} from "react-native";
import {connect} from 'react-redux'


class VerifyScreen extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
        <View>
          <Button
                  title="Get facebook Access Token"
                  onPress={()=>  
                   //I get undefined data when I console.log
         console.log(this.state.facebookToken,'this.state.facebookToken')}/>
          <Text style={{ fontSize: 20 }}>{this.props.facebookToken}</Text>
        </View>
        );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        facebookToken: state.facebookToken
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(VerifyScreen)

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center'
    }
});
```

In my LoginScreen, when I console.log `this.state.facbookToken` I get the data, but when I navigate to the nextScreen(VerifyScreen) and console.log it, I get `undefined`.

My question: how could I call global state from the VerifyScreen? 
I am very new to redux so I might be doing things wrong. Any advise or comments would really help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your verify screen, you try to console log this.state.facebookToken which definitely undefined. Instead try to update the code to `this.props.facebookToken`

```
console.log(this.props.facebookToken,'this.props.facebookToken')}/>
```

`this.state` is meant to hold component level state, when you talk about global state, redux state are sitting in `this.props.xxx` depending on the `mapStateToProps` method you defined

**UPDATES**:

The problems that you're violating is,

You're not passing payload to reducer when you dispatch action

```
increaseCounter: ()=>dispatch({ type: 'UPDATE', payload: state.facebookToken })
```

Then in your `App.js`, you have the following code

```
switch (action.type) {
  case 'UPDATE':
    return { facebookToken: state.facebookToken}
}
```

If you look at the code above, u can notice that Redux's flow work like this, we try to dispatch an `action`, which is an action object with two property, `type` and `payload` (payload is optional, or u can name it whatever you like), then in your reducer, you can access the `payload` as below

```
switch (action.type) {
  case 'UPDATE':
    return { facebookToken: action.payload };
}
```

you might be wondering what is `action.payload`, which we provide the value when we dispatch earlier `dispatch({ type: 'UPDATE', payload: state.facebookToken })`, so `action.payload` simply is `state.facebookToken`

**Extra**:

Depending on your use case of course, but typically when we return a state in reducer, we would want to return all the other states, and only update the particular states that is changed, for example as below:

```
console.log(action);
switch (action.type) {
  case 'UPDATE':
    return { ...state, facebookToken: state.facebookToken };
}
```

Often when I'm trying to debug the problem with Redux, I will do a `console.log` before the `switch` statement to find out what are the type i'm dispatching, and the payload I'm passing, and hence `console.log(action)` which you will be able to see the `type` property, and the value of `payload` property

Comment: Thank you very much for the comment it really helps. But I changed the code to `this.props.facebookToken` but still getting `null`. Do you have idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: thank you very much for the explanation. Pretty sure you explained perfectly and I want to accept your answer. But I am still a little confused about redux, so could you please provide the full code such as `App.js`, `LoginScreen.js` and 'VerifyScreen.js` this would be really helpful.

Comment: I will do that during my free time but unfortunately not at this moment. You should really try to digest the information and try it out yourself, reason is all these packages changes rather quickly, so don't get panic and try to fix it by yourself one at a time, cheers :D

Comment: I understand. I'll try it out! One question though. Notice that I didn't call function, `increaseCounter` in my `LoginScreen` should I call somewhere in `<LoginButton/>`

Comment: Yup that's right! `this.setState({facebookToken:data.accessToken}, () =>  this.props. increaseCounter()`, You can do it after you login, or you have any specific workflow, dispatch anytime you want

Comment: I edited my code as you guided. If you see my App.js and LoginScreen.js I updated the code. But I am not getting the global state. Notice in my loginScreen, I get `undefined` for `this.props.facebookToken` and an error for `call global state` button. Any idea why? This is getting really frustrated..

Comment: Figured it out! had to define the state like `function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    updateState: (state) => dispatch({ type: 'UPDATE', payload: state.facebookToken }),
  } 
}` then `onPress={() => this.props.updateState(this.state)}`

Comment: I'll share you a `snack` on coming weekend when I'm free, sharing you some common practice to improve readability. Stay tune!

Comment: @kirimi: Hi Kirimi, you can have at look at https://github.com/isaaclem/manager/blob/master/src/components/LoginForm.js to show how the password and username being key-in and updated the redux state as well as clicking button to login

Comment: @Isaac Hi I am trying to send data from a child component to parent on button click so that I can use it in parent but while accessing the data in parent. I am not getting the data in state when a button is clicked in child component. Can you please help me out. PLEASE

Comment: @amitpandya: Please post another question by itself :)